# How to trigger methods with UIButtonBarItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a a xib with a toolbar and on that I have 2 buttons all made in IB.
I can connect my outlets to the buttons but when I click them the method isn't triggered?
Why is that?

In my header file I have this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cancelEntry;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveEntry;

-(IBAction) cancelEntry:(id) sender;
-(IBAction) saveEntry:(id) sender;
```

In my .m file I got this:

```
-(IBAction) cancelEntry:(id) sender {
 NSLog(@"cancel");
}

-(IBAction) saveEntry:(id) sender {
 NSLog(@"save");
}
```

All compiles as it should but no nothing in the log when clicking the buttons.
What should I do to get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you connected your outlets to the buttons, but didn't connect the buttons to the actions.

1. Right click Cancel the `UIBarButtonItem` in Interface Builder.
2. Hover over Selector, then drag the + that appears onto File's Owner.
3. Connect it to cancelEntry:.
4. Repeat for Save.

Instead of using `(id)` for your IBActions, you should probably use `(UIBarButtonItem *)`. That'll prevent you from connecting a different object type to those IBActions.

Comment: Thank you tweha! Even though I solved it myself your answer is correct and what I didn't do.